# .Net Maui - Windows - How can I add global keyboard and mouse event listeners?

Tags: .net, maui

My application requires supporting a timeout for user inactivity (it's deployed in a regulated industry).

For the windows version (old UWP in Xamarin), in the UWP project I could do this in MainPage.xaml.cs (which inherited from Xamarin.Forms.Platform.UWP.WindowsPage):

```
protected override void OnCharacterReceived(CharacterReceivedRoutedEventArgs e)
{
    base.OnCharacterReceived(e);
    this.pageService.ExtendSession();
}

protected override void OnDoubleTapped(DoubleTappedRoutedEventArgs e)
{
    base.OnDoubleTapped(e);
    this.pageService.ExtendSession();
}

protected override void OnKeyDown(KeyRoutedEventArgs e)
{
    base.OnKeyDown(e);
    this.pageService.ExtendSession();
}

protected override void OnKeyUp(KeyRoutedEventArgs e)
{
    base.OnKeyUp(e);
    this.pageService.ExtendSession();
}

protected override void OnTapped(TappedRoutedEventArgs e)
{
    base.OnTapped(e);
    this.pageService.ExtendSession();
}

protected override void OnPointerMoved(PointerRoutedEventArgs e)
{
    base.OnPointerMoved(e);
    this.pageService.ExtendSession();
}

protected override void OnPointerPressed(PointerRoutedEventArgs e)
{
    base.OnPointerPressed(e);
    this.pageService.ExtendSession();
}

protected override void OnPointerReleased(PointerRoutedEventArgs e)
{
    base.OnPointerReleased(e);
    this.pageService.ExtendSession();
}
```

In MAUI, however, there is no MainPage inheriting from WindowsPage at the platform level.

How can I achieve this in Maui?  FWIW - the old iOS and Android implementations still work fine, but there doesn't appear to be a hook in Maui for the Windows platform.

Thanks!

Editorial: I have been using Xamarin since version 1 (Pre-Microsoft acquisition), and now have to convert an enterprise-level app to .Net Maui.  It's a bit like going back many years due to the "quirks" that haven't been ironed out yet but were rock-solid in Xamarin by the time Forms 3 came out.

I haven't found any solution to this, even by searching the Github repo for the Maui source code.

Answer (score 0):

For now, .NET MAUI does not have a global API to capture keyboard and mouse events for Windows.

However, there is a workaround that you can use the [Hooks](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/winmsg/about-hooks) via Win32 API to pinvoke `SetWindowsHookEx` to detect the keyboard and mouse events.

Here are the steps to [import the WinAPI and use the Hooks to get the keyboard events](https://github.com/microsoft/microsoft-ui-xaml/issues/7330#issuecomment-1177555202).